# Power BI, I need to calculate sold product between two date

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

i'm new in power bi and i need some help.

i need to calculate total sold product between two dates, e.g. from 5 Feb 2021 to 5 apr 2021, i cant find any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have **sales** table with two column **Date** and **Amount**. Now you can create your **measure** as below-

```
total_sold = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(sales[amount]),
    DATESBETWEEN(
        sales[date],
        start_date,
        end_date
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a card or table and drag your no. of products sold column to the card, and use the filter on the date column to get the total no. of products sold in the time period.

*Note:- Please be a little more specific and descriptive the next time.*